# Activity stream database design laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wonder how to make notification like facebook does. So for example there user A,B and C.

User A create new post#1 and then B and C were commented on it, and then now I want A, B and C get notification everytime there is a new comment posted.

I dont know how to make database tables for this.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

The `Post` table, the `PostSubscribers` table and the `Users` table.

When user left a comment entry at `PostSubscribers` is created.

And you should send notification to all postSubscribers which are connected with post. Typical many-to-many relation.

User could abandon his subscription. In that case just remove entry from `PostSubscribers`.